# django virtualenv vs repository packages

Tags: django, virtualenv

I'm new to django and I'm trying to find out which way to build project is better:

- Build own virtualenv for each (including core django packages, which available via systemm repository) project

or

- use packages from debian repository (if available, otherwise put it in virtualenv).

As I understand, in case any security update the repository version will receive patch asap, however virtualenv version I'll need patch myself.
However in case of movement to another server virtual will cause less issues, then repository version.

What is the best practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know `virtualenv` is used by almost every django developer.

It is also good practice to have versions in your `requirements.txt` so that if some of the packages change you'll have your project working in production.

I think `virtualenv` is de facto the `best practice` for development with Python (not just with Django)